# LINE-HEIGHT não está funcionando em minha tabela

Tags: html, css, div, table

```css
* {
 font-family: arial;
}
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.escopo {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: yellow;
}
.margem_escopo {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: auto;
}
.tabela {
 border: 1px solid;
 width: 350px;
 height: 198px;
 background-color: red;
 margin: auto;
}
.style_tabela {
 margin: auto;
}
td {
 border: 1px solid;
 
}
tr {
 border: 1px solid;
}
td.verde:hover{
     
     background-color: green;
     /*display: block;*/
    }
table.style_tabela {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
 <html lang = "pt-br">
  <head>
   
   <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
   <title>Cabeçalho</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   
   <div class = "escopo">
    
    <div class = "margem_escopo">
     
     <div class = "tabela">
      
      <table class = "style_tabela" >
       <tr>
        
        <td class = "verde">Gomo</td>
        <td>Tesla</td>
        <td>Riuta</td>
        <td>Ferna</td>
        <td>Romã</td>
        <td>Célula</td>
        <td>Atacado</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        
        <td>Gomo</td>
        <td>Tesão</td>
        <td>Riuta</td>
        <td>Ferna</td>
        <td>Romã</td>
        <td>Célula</td>
        <td>Atacado</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Queria que ele ficasse assim...

[image: Já tentei de tudo mas as características só se inserem nas células.]

Aguardo retorno de vocês!

Comment: Julio, teu código CSS não tem nenhum `line-height` sendo definido.

Comment: Exatamente. Quando eu coloco em qualquer DIV da tag TABLE ele fica estranho. Basta inserir que vc vai ver.

Comment: Eu aprendi que era para alinhar verticalmente textos. Como devo fazer com essa tabela?

Comment: Você já pensou em utilizar o display: flex;?

Comment: Posso inserir direto na CLASS DIV que comporta a tabela?

Comment: Veja a resposta que coloquei, creio que te ajude!

Comment: Você quer alinhar o que? A tabela no centro da `<div>` verticalmente?
Sua pergunta tem apenas códigos e 1 imagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolvermos esse tipo de problema, o método mais recomendado é o **display: flex;**

Tente alterar o **css** da sua **.tabela** para a seguinte forma:

```
.tabela {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 350px;
    height: 198px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
}
```

Creio que seja essa a resposta que você necessita.

Veja esse guia para lhe auxiliar melhor com o **flex**:
https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/

Comment: Cara você simplesmente resolveu o problema da forma mais objetiva e direta!

Comment: Que bom que te ajudou cara!

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue centralizar usando `translateY(-50%)`, mas é preciso usar também `top: 50%` e `position: relative` na tabela.

```css
* {
 font-family: arial;
}
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.escopo {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: yellow;
}
.margem_escopo {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: auto;
}
.tabela {
 border: 1px solid;
 width: 350px;
 height: 198px;
 background-color: red;
 margin: auto;
}
.style_tabela {
 margin: auto;
}
td {
 border: 1px solid;
 
}
tr {
 border: 1px solid;
}
td.verde:hover{
     
     background-color: green;
     /*display: block;*/
    }
table.style_tabela {
 border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
 <html lang = "pt-br">
  <head>
   
   <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
   <title>Cabeçalho</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   
   <div class = "escopo">
    
    <div class = "margem_escopo">
     
     <div class = "tabela">
      
      <table class = "style_tabela" >
       <tr>
        
        <td class = "verde">Gomo</td>
        <td>Tesla</td>
        <td>Riuta</td>
        <td>Ferna</td>
        <td>Romã</td>
        <td>Célula</td>
        <td>Atacado</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Gomo</td>
        <td>Tesão</td>
        <td>Riuta</td>
        <td>Ferna</td>
        <td>Romã</td>
        <td>Célula</td>
        <td>Atacado</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Ou então usando flexbox na div onde está a tabela com a propriedade `justify-content: center`:

```css
* {
 font-family: arial;
}
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.escopo {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: yellow;
}
.margem_escopo {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: auto;
}
.tabela {
 border: 1px solid;
 width: 350px;
 height: 198px;
 background-color: red;
 margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.style_tabela {
 margin: auto;
}
td {
 border: 1px solid;
 
}
tr {
 border: 1px solid;
}
td.verde:hover{
     
     background-color: green;
     /*display: block;*/
    }
table.style_tabela {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
 <html lang = "pt-br">
  <head>
   
   <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
   <title>Cabeçalho</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   
   <div class = "escopo">
    
    <div class = "margem_escopo">
     
     <div class = "tabela">
      
      <table class = "style_tabela" >
       <tr>
        
        <td class = "verde">Gomo</td>
        <td>Tesla</td>
        <td>Riuta</td>
        <td>Ferna</td>
        <td>Romã</td>
        <td>Célula</td>
        <td>Atacado</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Gomo</td>
        <td>Tesão</td>
        <td>Riuta</td>
        <td>Ferna</td>
        <td>Romã</td>
        <td>Célula</td>
        <td>Atacado</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```